# Notation for proper classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, set-theory

Is it common to use curly brackets for proper classes, as we do for sets? For example, is it allowed to write

$$ \{\text{isomorphism classes of objects in } \mathcal{C}\} $$

where $\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary category?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: If you are going to write English, just write English: "the set of isomorphism classes of objects in $C$", the braces add no value.

Comment: @ Rob Arthan: I would like to define a bijection between the classes of isomorphism classes of objects in two (not necessarily small) categories.